# Query regarding xmlhttp.open

Tags: ajax

Experts i need your help

Can i pass a server url in xmlhttp.open parameter list
eg: `xmlhttp1.open("GET","http://10.6.10.222/DEV/Cgate/dailystat.txt",true);`

I am unable to pass a server url(second parameter) and get no response

Answer (score 0):

Any url that can be accessed by the browser can be called using a ajax call.

If you can directly access your server in the browser then you can call it.

**EDIT**
You cannot make a cross domain call. For that you need special permission set.

Comment: I am able to access the text file using the browser.can there be any permission issues

Comment: I think the domain the page from where you are making ajax call and the server are not on the same domain. If thats the case then you need permission.

Comment: Thanks a lot,so does the permission needs to be set in the scripting language that i use...in this case it is php

Comment: Have a look here. http://jquery-howto.blogspot.dk/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html